# Inserting a Derivative with Respect to a Variable Inside a Multiple Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I understand when it is legal to insert a derivative with respect to, say A, inside a double or triple integral with respect to B and C (where A, B, and C are independent variables)

Or can I insert the derivative inside the first integral? Or mix the orders and placement of the three?

Can I also ask what topic in advanced Calculus is this?

Comment: I recommend to write the question rather than using work